# How to place custom layer inside a in-built pre trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

We're trying to add a custom layer inside a pre-trained imagenet model. For a sequential or non-sequential model, we can easily do that. But here are some requirements.

First of all, we **don't wanna disclose** the whole imagenet model and deal with the **desired inside layer**. Let's say for `DenseNet` we need the following layers and further get the output shape of theirs to connect with some custom layers.

```py
vision_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(
    input_shape=(224,224,3),
    include_top = False, 
     weights='imagenet')

for i, layer in enumerate(vision_model.layers):
    if layer.name in ['conv3_block12_concat', 'conv4_block24_concat']:
        print(i,'\t',layer.trainable,'\t  :',layer.name)

        if layer.name == 'conv3_block12_concat':
            print(layer.get_output_shape_at(0)[1:])  # (28, 28, 512)

        if layer.name == 'conv4_block24_concat':
            print(layer.get_output_shape_at(0)[1:])  # (14, 14, 1024)
```

The whole requirement can be demonstrated as follows

[image: deit]

> The green indicator is basically the transition layer of the dense net.

In the above diagram, the dense net model has (let's say) `5 blocks` and among them, we want to pick `block 3` and `block 4` and add some custom layers followed by merging them to lead the final output.

Also, the blocks of `DenseNet` (block 1 to 5), should be as disclose as possible with their pre-trained imagenet weights. We like to have control to freeze and unfreeze pre-trained layers when we need them.

How can we efficiently achieve with `tf.keras`? or, If you think there some better approach to do the same thing, please suggest.

---

Let's say, a custom block is something like this

```py
class MLPBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel_num=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'):
        super(ConvModule, self).__init__()
        # conv layer
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_num, 
                        kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                        strides=strides, padding=padding)
        # batch norm layer
        self.bn   = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
        return tf.nn.relu(x)
```

#### Motivation

I'm trying to implement [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1361841520302103) paper-work where they did something like this. Initially, the paper was free to get but now it's not. But below is the main block diagram of their approach.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to the paper so I just build an example like the one your draw:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

class ConvBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel_num=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
        # conv layer
        self.conv = layers.Conv2D(kernel_num, 
                        kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                        strides=strides, padding=padding)
        # batch norm layer
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
        return tf.nn.relu(x)

vision_model = keras.applications.DenseNet121(
    input_shape=(224,224,3),
    include_top = False,
    weights='imagenet')

# Control freeze and unfreeze over blocks
def set_freeze(block, unfreeze):
    for layer in block:
        layer.trainable = unfreeze

block_1 = vision_model.layers[:7]
block_2 = vision_model.layers[7:53]
block_3 = vision_model.layers[53:141]
block_4 = vision_model.layers[141:313]
block_5 = vision_model.layers[313:]

set_freeze(block_1, unfreeze=False)
set_freeze(block_2, unfreeze=False)

for i, layer in enumerate(vision_model.layers):
    print(i,'\t',layer.trainable,'\t  :',layer.name)

layer_names = ['conv3_block12_concat', 'conv4_block24_concat', 'conv5_block16_concat']
vision_model_outputs = [vision_model.get_layer(name).output for name in layer_names]

custom_0 = ConvBlock()(vision_model_outputs[0])
custom_1 = ConvBlock()(layers.UpSampling2D(2)(vision_model_outputs[1]))
cat_layer = layers.concatenate([custom_0, custom_1])

last_conv_num = 2
custom_2 = layers.UpSampling2D(4)(vision_model_outputs[2])
outputs = layers.concatenate([ConvBlock()(cat_layer) for i in range(last_conv_num)] + [custom_2])
model = models.Model(vision_model.input, outputs)

keras.utils.plot_model(model, "./Model_structure.png", show_shapes=True)
```

Run the code and you will see the `block1` and `block2` are frozen,

Because the plot of full model is long so I just post few snippet of it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: More than I expected. Thank you. :)

Comment: Glad to help : )