# Understand and Implement Element-Wise Attention Module

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Please add a minimum comment on your thoughts so that I can improve my query. Thank you.  -)

---

I'm trying to understand and implement a research work on [Triple Attention Learning](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1361841520302103), which consists on

```
- channel-wise attention  (a)
- element-wise attention  (b)
- scale-wise attention    (c)
```

The mechanism is integrated experimentally inside the `DenseNet` model. The arch of the whole model's diagram is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu8Yy.png). The **channel-wise** attention module is simply nothing but the **squeeze and excitation** block. That gives a `sigmoid` output further to the **element-wise** attention module. Below is the more precise feature flow diagram of these modules (`a`, `b`, and `c`).

[image]

---

#### Theory

For the most part, I was able to understand and implement it but was a bit lost in the `Element-Wise` attention section (part `b` from the above diagram). This is where I need your assistance. -)

Here is a little theory on this topic to give you a rough idea of what all this is about. Please note, The paper is not openly accessible **now** but at its early stage of release on the publisher page **it was** free to get and I saved it at that time. And to be fair to all, I'm sharing it with you, [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BtH2qnAxWzGVScJ9tW4nGlZI0MI5IGGu/view?usp=sharing). Anyway, from the paper (Section **4.3**) it shows:

[image]

So **first** of all, `f(att)` function (which is in the first inplace diagram, left-middle part or `b`) consists of three convolution layers with **512** kernels with `1 x 1`, **512** kernels with `3 x 3` and `C` kernels with `1 x 1`. Here `C` is the number of the classifier. And with `Softmax` activation!

Next, it applies to the `Channel-Wise` attention module which we mentioned that simply a `SENet` module and gave a `sigmoid` probability score i.e `X(CA)`. So, from the function of `f(att)`, we're getting `C` times `softmax` probability scores and each of these scores get multiplied with `sigmoid` output and finally produces feature maps `A` (according to the equation **4** of the above diagram).

**Second**, there is a `C` linear classifier that implemented as a `1 x 1` - `C` kernels convolution layer. This layer also applied to the `SENet` module's output i.e. `X(CA)`, to each feature vector pixel-wise. And in the end, it gives an output of feature maps `S` (equation **5** shown below diagram).

And **Third**, they element-wise multiply each confidence score (of `S`) with the corresponding attention element `A`. This multiplication is on purpose. They did it for preventing unnecessary attention on the feature maps.  To make it effective, they also use the `weighted cross-entropy` loss function to minimize it here between the classification **ground truth** and the **score vector**.

[image]

**My Query**

Mostly I don't get properly the minimization strategies in the middle of the network. I want someone who can give me a proper understanding and implementation of this `element-wise attention mechanism in detail that proposed in the mentioned paperwork (section **4.3**).

---

### Implement

Here is a minimum code to get started. It should enough I guess. This is shallow implementation but too much away from the original element-wise module. I'm not sure how to implement it properly. For now, I want it as a layer that supposed to plug and play to any model. I was trying with MNIST and a simple `Conv` net.

In a summary, for MNIST, we should have a network that contains both the `channel-wise` and `element-wise` attention model followed by the last **10** unit `softmax` layer. So for example:

```
Net: Conv2D - Attentions-Module - GAP - Softmax(10)
```

The `Attention-Module` consists of those two-part: `Channel-wise` and `Element-wise`, and the `Element-wise`supposed to have `Softmax` too that minimizes weighted `CE` loss function to `ground-truth` and `score vector` coming from this module (according to the paperwork, already described above too). The module also passes **weighted feature maps** to the consecutive layers. For more clarity here is a simple schematic diagram of what we're looking for

[image]

Ok, for the `channel-wise` attention which should give us a single probability score (`sigmoid`), let's use a fake layer for now for simplicity:

```
class FakeSE(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        # conv layer
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10, padding='same',
                                           kernel_size=3)
    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv(input_tensor)
        return tf.math.sigmoid(x)
```

And for the `element-wise` attention part, following is the failed attempt so far:

```
class ElementWiseAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        # for simplicity the f(attn) function here has 2 convolution instead of 3
        # self.conv1, and self.conv2
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 
                                            kernel_size=1, 
                                            strides=1, padding='same',
                                            use_bias=True, activation=tf.nn.silu)

        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10, 
                                            kernel_size=1, 
                                            strides=1, padding='same',
                                            use_bias=False, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)
        
        # fake SENet or channel-wise attention module 
        self.cam = FakeSE()
        
        # a linear layer 
        self.linear = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10,
                                           kernel_size=1,
                                           strides=1, padding='same',
                                           use_bias=True, activation=None)
        
        super(ElementWiseAttention, self).__init__()
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        # 2 stacked conv layer (in paper, it's 3. we set 2 for simplicity)
        # this is the f(att)
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        
        # this is the A = f(att)*X(CA)
        camx = self.cam(x)*x
        
        # this is S = X(CA)*Linear_Classifier
        linx = self.cam(self.linear(inputs))

        # element-wise multiply to prevent unnecessary attention
        # suppose to minimize with weighted cross entorpy loss 
        out = tf.multiply(camx, linx)
        
        return out
```

The above one is the **Layer of Interest**. If I understand the paper words correctly, this layer should not only minimize the weighted loss function to `gt` and `score_vector` but also produce some weighted feature maps (`2D`).

### Run

Here is the toy data

```
(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_train = tf.image.resize(x_train, [32,32]) # if we want to resize 
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train , num_classes=10) 

# Model 
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,1))
efnet = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(weights=None,
                                             include_top = False, 
                                             input_tensor = input)
em =  ElementWiseAttention()(efnet.output)
# Now that we apply global max pooling.
gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(em)

# classification layer.
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(gap)

# bind all
func_model = tf.keras.Model(efnet.input, output)
func_model.compile(
          loss      = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics   = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
# fit 
func_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=3, verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Understanding the element-wise attention

When paper introduce they method they said:

> The attention modules aim to exploit the relationship between disease
> labels and (1) diagnosis-specific feature channels, (2)
> diagnosis-specific locations on images (i.e. the regions of thoracic
> abnormalities), and (3) diagnosis-specific scales of the feature maps.

(1), (2), (3) corresponding to channel-wise attention, element-wise attention, scale-wise attention

We can tell that element-wise attention is for deal with disease location & weight info, i.e: **at each location on image, how likely there is a disease**, as it been mention again when paper introduce the element-wise attention：

> The element-wise attention learning aims to enhance the sensitivity of feature
> representations to thoracic abnormal regions, while suppressing the activations when there is no abnormality.

OK, we could easily get location & weight info for one disease, but we have multiple disease:

> Since there are multiple thoracic diseases, we choose to estimate an
> element-wise attention map for each category in this work.

We could store the multiple disease location & weight info by using a tensor `A` with shape `(height, width, number of disease)`:

> The all-category attention map is denoted by A ∈ RH×W×C, where each
> element aijc is expected to represent the relative importance at location (i, j) for
> identifying the c-th category of thoracic abnormalities.

And we have linear classifiers for produce a tensor `S` with same shape as `A`, this can be interpret as:

**At each location on feature maps `X(CA)`, how confident those linear classifiers think there is certain disease at that location**

Now we element-wise multiply `S` and `A` to get `M`, i.e we are:

> prevent the attention maps from paying unnecessary attention to those
> location with non-existent labels

So after all those, we get tensor `M` which tells us:

**location & weight info about certain disease that linear classifiers are confident about it**

Then if we do `global average pooling` over `M`, we get prediction of weight for each disease, add another `softmax` (or `sigmoid`) we could get prediction of probability for each disease

Now since we have label and prediction, so, naturally we could minimizing loss function to optimize the model.

### Implementation

Following code is tested on **colab** and will show you how to implement channel-wise attention and element-wise attention, and build and training a simple model base on your code with DenseNet121 and without scale-wise attention:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ALPHA = 1/16
C = 10
D = 128

class ChannelWiseAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChannelWiseAttention, self).__init__()

        # squeeze
        self.gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        
        # excitation
        self.fc0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(int(ALPHA * D), use_bias=False, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        
        self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(D, use_bias=False, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)

        # reshape so we can do channel-wise multiplication
        self.rs = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 1, D))

    def call(self, inputs):
        # calculate channel-wise attention vector
        z = self.gap(inputs)
        u = self.fc0(z)
        u = self.fc1(u)
        u = self.rs(u)
        return u * inputs

class ElementWiseAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ElementWiseAttention, self).__init__()

        # f(att)
        self.conv0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 
                                            kernel_size=1, 
                                            strides=1, padding='same',
                                            use_bias=True, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 
                                            kernel_size=3, 
                                            strides=1, padding='same',
                                            use_bias=True, activation=tf.nn.relu)

        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(C, 
                                            kernel_size=1, 
                                            strides=1, padding='same',
                                            use_bias=False, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)
        
        # linear classifier
        self.linear = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(C,
                                           kernel_size=1,
                                           strides=1, padding='same',
                                           use_bias=True, activation=None)
        
        # for calculate score vector to training element-wise attention module
        self.gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.sfm = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()

    def call(self, inputs):
        # f(att)
        a = self.conv0(inputs)
        a = self.conv1(a)
        a = self.conv2(a)
        
        # confidence score
        s = self.linear(inputs)

        # element-wise multiply to prevent unnecessary attention 
        m = s * a
        # using to minimize with weighted cross entorpy loss
        y_hat = self.gap(m)
        # could also using sigmoid like in paper
        out = self.sfm(y_hat)

        return m, out

(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_train = tf.image.resize(x_train, [32,32]) # if we want to resize 
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train , num_classes=10) 

# Model 
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,1))
efnet = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(weights=None,
                                             include_top = False, 
                                             input_tensor = input)

xca = ChannelWiseAttention()(efnet.get_layer("conv3_block1_0_bn").output)
m, output =  ElementWiseAttention()(xca)

# bind all
func_model = tf.keras.Model(efnet.input, output)
func_model.compile(
          loss      = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics   = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
# fit 
func_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=3, verbose = 1)
```

PS: Serendipity, I also answered your another question related to this paper few month back:

[How to place custom layer inside a in-built pre trained model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477554/how-to-place-custom-layer-inside-a-in-built-pre-trained-model/65487100#65487100)

Comment: I had a feeling you would come -). Thanks for your detailed answer. I will check it and will inform you back. :)

Comment: @M.Innat take your time, feel free to ask if you find any question in my answer : )

Comment: No query. Thanks again to the man behind that Mask. -)

Comment: @M.Innat glad to help, beneath this mask there is more than flesh, beneath this mask there is an idea : ) man I wait to say this quote for so long, have a good day : )

Comment: poetry <3 <3 <3

Comment: Anyway, just to inform you, in your code, there's some little gap. You took the output of element-wise attn and set it as  `model(.. output)` but according to the paper (section `4.3` last paragraph), it should be the auxiliary classifier. While navigating your code, I remembered [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274286/google-inception-modelwhy-there-is-multiple-softmax) strategy. It's kind of similar. But it's ok, I get it. -)

Comment: @M.Innat Yes, of course, it should be auxiliary classifier, my example code just for showing how to implement the mechanism, not intent to build exactly the model that paper proposed, but I guess it's OK for you since you get it : )